# Convert text from database to any language for MVC-Umbraco Multilingual Site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, umbraco

We are developing an MVC-Umbraco Multilingual Site, Following are the sections in my page

- **Section 1** - Text from Umbraco(English,Spanish,Hindi,German will be separate nodes in content)
- **Section 2** - Few input fields which are marked as required fields.
- **Section 3** - List of Users already available. List of users are displayed as Grid and we are using MVCGrid
- **Section 4** - A scroll section where Firm Names are scrolling towards left.

Please note the Firm Names and User-list are coming from MVC database. My site has section English,Spanish,Hindi and German, when the user takes Spanish URL the above Page should be in Spanish completely.

We achieved following sections successfully Section 1, Section 2(By adding a resource file).But Section 3 and Section 4, I couldn't translate. Is there any package to convert any text from database to any language in MVC other than Google API.

Comment: Why would you translate Users and Firm names. They're names, you don't need to translate them...

Comment: @CallumLinington My requirement is in my Spanish page, I want to display Username in Spanish.

Comment: But a username is name, my name in spanish is Callum. In english its Callum. Am I getting the wrong end of the stick? user2646320 in spanish is user2646320

Comment: @CallumLinington Sorry I don't know Spanish, may be in Spanish the name is same but say if my page is in Arabic or Hindi Language then I want name in corresponding language

Comment: But you said you only wanted English or Spanish. I'm pretty sure that you still wouldn't translate the names... mostly because they wouldn't translate properly.

Comment: @CallumLinington I updated my question. My client want to translate the name and few user inputted fields.

Comment: From what I understand is when you want to translate something, you find someone who natively speaks the language and pay them some money. I've always been told that a person translator is always tonnes better than a computer translator because of the factors you have to take into account when translating.

Comment: @CallumLinington Practically its not possible. I am looking for C# code.

Comment: Have any one faced this issue?